# OleMenuCommand not triggered on files under a website project

Tags: c#, .net, envdte, vs-extensibility

I'm implementing a `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package` that adds a command in the context menu, when a Solution Explorer item is clicked.

The code that adds the command looks something like this:

```
_oleMenuCommandService = GetService(typeof (IMenuCommandService)) as OleMenuCommandService;
if (_oleMenuCommandService != null)
{
    var menuCommandId = new CommandID(GuidList.guidErsx_Net_VsixCmdSet, (int) PkgCmdIDList.sortResx);
    var menuItem = new OleMenuCommand(MenuItemClick, StatusChanged, BeforeContextMenuOpens, menuCommandId);
    _oleMenuCommandService.AddCommand(menuItem);
}
```

The package is defined like this:

```
[PackageRegistration(UseManagedResourcesOnly = true)]
[InstalledProductRegistration("#110", "#112", "1.0", IconResourceID = 400)]
[ProvideMenuResource("Menus.ctmenu", 1)]
[Guid(GuidList.guidErsx_Net_VsixPkgString)]
[ProvideAutoLoad(VSConstants.UICONTEXT.SolutionExistsAndFullyLoaded_string)]
```

The command shows when any Solution Explorer item is right clicked, except any of the following:

- The item is under a website project
- The item is a csproj file
- The item is a folder

In these cases the events defined above are not fired at all.

**How can I cover these cases as well? Do I need to register something somewhere?**

Comment: You should post your .vsct file, it's the most important piece of information when a command doesn't show on the expected menu, context menu or toolbar

Comment: Forgot about that one.. I eventually marked this as a duplicate, finding that I should have added IDM_VS_CTXT_WEBITEMNODE as another parent.